# Aligning Text and Icons in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a site with Bootstrap 3. I am trying to align some text and icons properly. For instance, I want to show the following:

```
[icon] 12 products
```

and

```
visit now [icon]
```

In the first, the glyphicon is shown to the left of the text. In the second, the glyphicon is shown to the right of the text. My problem is, no matter what I do, the text is not vertically aligned with the icon properly. For instance, with the following HTML, the label appears several pixels lower than the icon. I want the text vertically centered with the icon or vice versa. I just don't want it to look so janky.

```
<ul class="list-inline pull-right">
  <li><span class="pull-right">visit now</span></li>
  <li style="padding-left:0px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></i></li>
</ul>
```

I'm not sure how to fix this so the text aligns correctly.

Comment: Why is your icon in a separate list item to the text?

Comment: try image icon and text in the same li.

Comment: @CodeLღver when I put the icon and text n the same li, the text still appears several pixels lower than the icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working just fine.  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/544wkbm2/)

```
<ul class="list-inline pull-right">
  <li><span>visit now</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></i></li>
</ul>
```